# Multiple where or slow in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `logs` where I store changes of a model. The table currently contains 55000 records.

Logs table

```
id: int(10)
model: varchar(191)
model_key: varchar(191)
backend_user_id: int(10)
changes: TEXT
created_at: TIMESTAMP
updated_at: TIMESTAMP
```

Index: `create index ix1 on logs (model, model_key, updated_at)`

The query I want to execute takes 0.080 second:

```sql
select * from `logs`
where (`model` = 'Oms\\Core\\Models\\Order' and `model_key` = 13763)
or (`model` = 'Oms\\Core\\Models\\Customer' and `model_key` = 13761)
or (`model` = 'Oms\\Core\\Models\\OrderRow' and `model_key` = 13764)
or (`model` = 'Oms\\Core\\Models\\Address' and `model_key` = 13763) 
order by `updated_at` desc limit 8 offset 0
```

Explain of the query:
[image]

How can is speed up this query?

Comment: 1) Do you need all columns`SELECT *`? 2) Covering index on `model, model_key, updated_at`

Comment: Do you have an index on model and model_key? When you run `EXPLAIN` what execution plan does it use?

Comment: Do you have a combined index, or just separate indexes on each field? The names visible in possible_keys of the explain suggests the latter. There is a difference.

Comment: @Uueerdo I've added an combined index on all three fields now, and now the query exectues in 0.080 sec. I still would like it to be faster, is that possible?

Comment: As an aside, the number in parentheses following an INT declaration (or TINYINT, BIGINT, etc) is almost meaningless, and may as well be omitted.

Comment: Can `updated_at` be null?

Comment: Also, which version of MySQL?

Comment: @Strawberry updated_at can be null and I'm running MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance you can add the following index:

```
create index ix1 on logs (model, model_key, updated_at)
```

Comment: With this index I get a result of 0.080 sec, is that the fastest mysql can do with this query?

Comment: I updated my question with the new results of your index.

Comment: @Jacob That doesn't look too bad. The "estimated filtered rows" is 34. It then just needs to sort them and keep the first 8 ones. Now, that is "estimate" only; reality may be different.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not handle `OR` conditions as well as it does `AND` ones; but has some optimizations for `IN` which can be used in place of some OR conditions. In addition to the compound index already suggested, you could modify your WHERE like so:

```
WHERE (`model`, `model_key`) IN (
    ('Oms\\Core\\Models\\Order', 13763)
   , ('Oms\\Core\\Models\\Customer', 13761)
   , ('Oms\\Core\\Models\\OrderRow', 13764)
   , ('Oms\\Core\\Models\\Address', 13763)
)
```

Also, from the data you have shown `model_key` is always an integer value; if that is always the case, I would suggest using a more appropriate type (like INT) as string comparison is generally much more expensive than int comparison.

Comment: Your suggestion brings the duration down to 0.062 sec :), maybe it can't be as fast as I would like to. The type isn't always `INT`, that's why `model_key` is a varchar.